# How to handle laravel TokenMismatchException when session expires

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, session

When the session is expired, User cant log back in without a page refresh because the `_token` in ajax headers is expired(AKA `TokenMismatchException`). I cant handle the exception by redirecting user to a log in page because the login is an overlay modal and the request is handled via ajax.

I thought i could catch the mismatch exception in `Handler.php` and return a json response with a session token. and on the client side, use the new token to continue the intended process. However, when i use the new token passed from server, the session token will be changed again on server side which results another `TokenMismatchException`.

So how should i handle the exception in a secured way without refreshing a page?

Here's what i have right now:

setup `csrf_token` in a global js file:

```
   $(function () {
       $.ajaxSetup({
         headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content') }
       });
     });
```

render method in app/exceptions/handler.php:

```
  public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {
        if ($this->isHttpException($e))
        {
            return $this->renderHttpException($e);
        }
        else if ($e instanceof TokenMismatchException)
        {
            if ($request->ajax()) {
                return response()->json([
                    'message' => 'TokenMismatchException',
                    'token' => csrf_token()
                ]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return parent::render($request, $e);
        }
    }
```

in authentication.js:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/auth/login",
    data: {
      "email" : $('#login_email').val(),
      "password" : $('#login_password').val(),
      'remember': $('#login_remember').is(':checked')
    },
    success: function(response) {
      if (response.message === 'TokenMismatchException') {
        console.log(response);  //message and token exist
        //if catch the exception, use the new token to set up the ajax headers and login again

           $.ajaxSettings.headers["X-CSRF-TOKEN"] = response.token;
           console.log($.ajaxSettings.headers["X-CSRF-TOKEN"]);
           $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "/auth/login",
             data: {
               "email" : $('#login_email').val(),
               "password" : $('#login_password').val(),
              'remember': $('#login_remember').is(':checked'),
             },
             success: function(res) {
               console.log(res);

             },
             error: function(err) {
               console.log(err);
             }
         });

      }
      console.log('logged in');  
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, err) {
    }
  });
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In your render function, you've to check for a specific TokenMismatchException. So may be you can try something like this:

```
   if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException) {
        return response()->json('msg', 'Your session has expired. Please try again.');
    }
```

You may also pass a new csrf_token along with the json so that you can replace the old one with the new one and send the form request again.

```
if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException) {
            return response()->json(['msg'=> 'Your session has expired. Please try again.', 'token'=> csrf_token()]);
        }
```

I haven't tested this code. But this should get you started.

Also, if you want, you can use a package: https://github.com/GeneaLabs/laravel-caffeine

Comment: Hey, I have done what youve suggested. please check my code. also, i believe laravel-caffeine currently only works for forms on a php page rather than ajax forms.

Comment: Seems okay to me. Did you try this code? A token mismatch is a security feature, so this approach would also open doors to anyone who's trying to post request to our server with invalid token.

Comment: doesnt work. second login in attempt also yields same exception. its because the session token on back end is refreshed again. do you have better solutions?